# How to get the name of the constant

Tags: ruby

```
module Colors
  Red = 0
  Blue = 1
  Green = 2
end
```

When I have the reference to the module `Colors`, I can get the name of that module `"Colors"` by `Colors.name`.

Is it possible to get the string representation of the constant `"Colors::Red"` when I have a reference to the constant `Colors::Red`?

Comment: No, it's not possible because you don't have a reference to the constant, you have a reference to the value of the constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, provided only one constant has a value equal to the value of the given reference.

```
def ref_to_str(value)
  k = Colors.constants.find { |k| Colors.const_get(k) == value }
  k.nil? ? nil : "Colors::#{k}"
end
```

```
ref_to_str(0)
  #=> "Colors::Red" 
ref_to_str(1)    
  #=> "Colors::Blue" 
ref_to_str(2)
  #=> "Colors::Green" 
ref_to_str(3)
  #=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if a built-in method existed for this.

Comment: You must be kidding :) `Colors` is _the constant_ of absolutely same nature as `Colors::Red`. They are both constants. Their names are to be retrieven _the same way_. While your answer has an added value, demonstrating introspection techniques etc, it is _not an answer to the question stated_. As Jordan pointed out in the comments to original question, in general it is impossible. For `Colors::Red` reference, as in your example, the answer would be `Colors::Red.to_s`. For `0` it is ambiguous (hence not defined): `class A; A1 = 0; A2 = 0; end`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`constants`](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Module/constants):

```
Colors.constants
```

so

- `Colors.constants[0].id2name` is `Red`
- `Colors.constants[1].id2name` is `Blue`
- `Colors.constants[2].id2name` is `Green`

Comment: Consider removing empty parentheses, to use them is not idiomatic ruby.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. It's only referencing the order that the constants are listed in the `Colors` module and not the actual value for each constant. In the example given, this works only because the sort order and values match.

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible to get the string representation as `Colors::Red` will refer to value of constant `Red` defined in module `Colors`.

```
        Colors::Red => 0
```

However, You can get the list of constants for the module using `Colors.constants`

```
        Colors.constants => [:Red, :Blue, :Green]
```

Answer (score 1):

`'Colors'` is *not* the name of the constant `Colors`, it is the name of the `Module` that has been assigned to the constant `Colors`. There is a *fundamental* difference between variables (and I include constants in this, together with local variables, instance variables, class variables, global variables, thread-local pseudo-globals, method-local pseudo-globals, and special variables) and objects, not the least of which is that objects are, well, objects (duh!) and variables are *not* objects! You cannot store them in variables, you cannot call methods on them, all you can do is assign them (at least some of them) and dereference them.

Since in an object-oriented language, method calling is pretty much all you can do, and you cannot call methods on variables because they aren't objects, there is no way that you can ask a variable questions such as "what is your name".

You can ask a `Module` for its name, because the [`Module`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html) class has a [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name) instance method that returns the `Module`'s name. [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html) doesn't have a `name` method, so you cannot ask an `Integer` for its name.

Note that the name of a `Module` is somewhat "magical". It is `nil` by default, but the first time you assign a `Module` to a constant, the name will become *some* representation of the path to said constant (basically the `name` of the enclosing module + `::` + the name of the constant). However, if you assign the module to a different constant, even if you [`remove_const`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) the constant, the name will still stay the same.

Here's a nice little snippet of code that demonstrates that `Module#name` really returns the name of the `Module`, not the name of the variable used to refer to it:

```
m = Module.new

m.name
# => nil

A = m

m.name
# => 'A'

A = nil
Object.send(:remove_const, :A) # just to be *really* sure

A
# NameError: uninitialized constant A

m.name
# => 'A'
```

So, in short: no, there is no way you can get the name of a constant (or any variable) from the object referenced by that constant, even if just because the object can be referenced by more than one variable, and then what name would you return?